# Hero Video isn't staying in it's container

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to have a fairly large hero video with a text overlay, but it's not fitting in the container and just covering up the whole page. It stays behind my other content though.

HTML:

```
<div class="intro">
            <video playsinline autoplay muted loop poster="placeholder.jpg" id="bgvideo" width="x" height="y">
                <source src="video/showreel.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
    display:block;
    position: fixed;
    width:100%;
    z-index: -100;
    overflow:hidden;
    padding-bottom:56.25%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `max-width: 100%;` to fit the large video instead of `width:100%;`
Try to use the `max-height:100%` property also.

Answer (score 0):

I actually was able to figure it out!

Can't remember everything I changed but

HTML

```
<div class="videocontainer">

            <div class="hero-text">
                <h1>Jill of All Trades</h1>
                <p>Master of Many. Front-End Developer. 3D Animator. Graphic Designer. <br>
                Dedicated creating beautiful interfaces and graphics.</p>
            </div>

            <div class="hero-overlay">
            </div>


            <video playsinline="playsinline" autoplay="autoplay" muted="muted" loop="loop">
                <source src="video/showreel.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
```

css

```
.videocontainer{
  position: static;
  background-color: black;
  height: 100vh;
  min-height: 25rem;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

video{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
```